# Create timestamp dynamically

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I am working with a PostgreSQL 8.3.3 database that stores military time as characers (don't ask ...) and I need to update a column which adds/subtracts time to a column that is a time itself. Some of the columns store only hours and minutes (HHMM or 1005) and some store hours, minutes, and seconds. So I'm left with parsing and extracting data.

I've been able to drum up this query:

```sql
UPDATE my_schema.tgtplsel ts
SET etd = subquery.new_etd
FROM ((SELECT 
        replace(((((interval '1 hours' * substring(starttime, 1, 2)::integer) +
        (interval '1 minutes' * substring(starttime, 3, 2)::integer)) + 

        ((interval '1 hours' * ((SELECT zuluoffset FROM my_schema.airports WHERE name = 'KABC'))) +
        (interval '1 minutes' * 0) +
        (interval '1 seconds' * 0))) +
        ((interval '1 hours' * substring(ts.taxidelay, 1, 2)::integer) +
        (interval '1 minutes' * substring(ts.taxidelay, 3, 2)::integer)) +

        ((interval '1 hours' * substring(ts.etd, 1, 2)::integer) +
        (interval '1 minutes' * substring(ts.etd, 3, 2)::integer))::time)::char(5), ':', '') as new_etd, ts.exerciseid

      FROM my_schema.tgtplsel as ts
      INNER JOIN my_schema.exerparm as ep ON ts.exerciseid = ep.exerciseid
      WHERE ts.exerciseid = 11
      AND ts.taxidelay is not null
      AND length(ts.taxidelay) > 0)) as subquery
WHERE ts.exerciseid = subquery.exerciseid 
AND ts.exerciseid = 11
AND ts.taxidelay is not null
AND length(ts.taxidelay) > 0
```

The subquery itself returns 16 rows, calculated correctly, ex:

```
0245
1050
0920
0345
1210
etc.
```

But in the `UPDATE` statement, all rows that meet the criteria in the `WHERE` clause (16 in the example) are updated with the FIRST value of the subquery (`0245`). Why?

And how can I get it to update each row with the correct value?

**To clarify:**
I'm trying to update the `ETD` column of the `tgtplsel` table with a value that is calculated from a couple of other fields.  The formula we are using to generate this new value is:

`ETD =  ((starttime - zuluoffset) + taxidelay + ETD)`

So if my ETD is 00:30, starttime is 23:00, zuluoffset is -5, and taxidelay is 0005, then the new ETD should be ((23:00 - (-5)) + 00:05 + 00:30) or 18:35. The reason for converting these to a `time` or `interval` type is because a starttime could be 02:00 or 2am, and if the zuluoffset is -5, then I need that to calculate properly to 21:00, not -03:00.  Some of these columns are of type `numeric` while others are `character` - totally out of my hands, so I'm trying my best to work my way around it.

I was able to create an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!10/abe8c/2) with some test data. Although some of my ETD values were supposed to be `0000` and if I do a `SELECT` in the fiddle, they come back as `0`.

Comment: You must provide the version of your software!

Comment: You're giving us the results, but not the data they're coming from. `-EPSYCHICPOWERSREQUIRED` . SQLFiddle? And, as Erwin says, *PostgreSQL version please*.

Comment: 8.3.3, sorry about that guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Basic query

Complex calculations aside, you can largely simplify the `UPDATE`, no subquery needed:

```sql
UPDATE my_schema.tgtplsel ts
SET    etd = <complex calculation>
FROM   my_schema.exerparm ep
WHERE  ep.exerciseid = ts.exerciseid 
AND    ts.exerciseid = 11
AND    ts.taxidelay is not null
AND    length(ts.taxidelay) > 0;
```

#### Calculations

The `<complex calculation>` can be rewritten as:

```sql
 to_char(to_timestamp(ep.starttime, 'HH24mi')::time
       + (SELECT interval '1h' * zuluoffset
          FROM my_schema.airports WHERE name = 'KABC')
       + to_timestamp(ts.taxidelay, 'HH24mi')::time::interval      
       + to_timestamp(ts.etd, 'HH24mi')::time::interval
       , 'HH24mi')
```

Operating with `timestamp`, `time` and `interval` would be the proper way. You seem to know that. While stuck with the unfortunate setup I'll assist with the **dark side**.

[`to_timestamp()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html) can take `time` as input. It prepends the *year 1*, which is irrelevant here, since we cast to `time` right away (which in turn can be cast to `interval`).

Use the function [`to_char()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html) to transform an `interval` back to `text`.

#### Functions

To make your life on the dark side a little brighter, create some of these conversion functions, which work with or without seconds:

Convert "military time" to time:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION f_mt2time(text)
  RETURNS time
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE AS
$func$
SELECT CASE
          WHEN length($1) = 4 THEN to_timestamp($1, 'HH24mi')::time
          ELSE                     to_timestamp($1, 'HH24miss')::time
       END
$func$;
```

Convert time to "military time":

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION f_time2mt(time)
  RETURNS text
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE AS
$func$
SELECT CASE
          WHEN extract(sec FROM $1) = 0 THEN to_char($1, 'HH24MI')
          ELSE                               to_char($1, 'HH24MISS')
       END
$func$;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=1d7b5da30ed44593cb2d1f467e7e8fc5)*
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/eb950/1)</sub>

#### Put it all together

Apply the aux. functions and extract the constant subquery for `zuluoffset` from the expression into the `FROM` list. Clearer and faster:

```sql
UPDATE my_schema.tgtplsel ts
SET    etd = f_time2mt(
                f_mt2time(ep.starttime)
              + z.zulu
              + f_mt2time(ts.taxidelay)::interval      
              + f_mt2time(ts.etd)::interval)
FROM   my_schema.exerparm ep
CROSS   JOIN (
   SELECT interval '1h' * zuluoffset AS zulu
   FROM   my_schema.airports
   WHERE  name = 'KABC'
   ) z
WHERE  ep.exerciseid = ts.exerciseid 
AND    ts.exerciseid = 11
AND    ts.taxidelay is not null
AND    length(ts.taxidelay) > 0;
```

Much better now.

Comment: Erwin....not too sure where to begin here.  It's amazing how you were able to come up with this with the little info that I originally posted.  I created a fiddle with some sample data in it and hope it helps with any questions, although you seemed to have figured it out pretty well.  I will run through this sql in the morning and let you know how it works.  Again, thanks for the detailed answer...far too often people nag on what someone is doing wrong and forget about the fact they need help with something.  This site is great at NOT doing that....much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks Erin, I was finally able to put the pieces together and get it working on my system...plus I understand a whole lot more about postgreSQL and its functions with your help.

Comment: Two missions accomplished! :)

Answer (score 0):

None of that string mangling should be necessary. Use the `extract` or `date_part` and `date_trunc` functions to get parts of timestamps. Use the `time` or `interval` data types as appropriate when you want to store partial timestamps like hour+day+second.

I haven't tried to write a replacement since you haven't posted the data/tables you're operating on or a clear explanation of what the whole query is supposed to do. I strongly suspect you'll have better results when you get rid of the string manipulation in favour of proper date/time processing functions, though.

- [Date/time data types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html)
- [Date/time functions and operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html)

Comment: Agreed about the string mangling...but I needed to put this statement together in a rush and was literally browsing Google on one pc while trying things on another...no excuse but I was just trying to go with what seemed to work at the time.  

I posted a fiddle link in my question with sample data and hope it makes a little more sense.  Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest changing:

```
AND length(ts.taxidelay) > 0)) as subquery
WHERE ts.exerciseid = subquery.exerciseid
```

to

```
AND length(ts.taxidelay) > 0)) as subquery
ON ts.exerciseid = subquery.exerciseid
```

Also, for troubleshooting, run your entire query as a select instead of an update.  It will help you see what's happening.

Comment: Why would you suggest `ON`? It makes no sense at all.